# Missing library symLite Ubuntu 14.10 x64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libraries

When I configure Extrae, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsymLite
```

I know that Ubuntu cannot find the symLite library but I don't know how to solve this problem. I didn't find this Library on Google. Any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The libsymLite library belongs to the [DynInst](http://dyninst.org) dynamic instrumentation library since version 8.0. The DynInst developers provide already built packages for Ubuntu in their webpage.